# how to change the value coming from controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i have small requirement that the value coming from the controller has to be changed to null by the jsp for the next task.

the value coming from the controller per se

model.addAttribute("message" "hi");

now the message has to be null (it should be done by jsp jstl)

how to make the message to null by jsp jstl.

i tried this..it is not working...

because for the next request it is still holding the value hi

```
<c:if test="${message!=''}">
        <c:set var="message" value="good" scope="page" />
        <c:out value="${message}"/> 
        </c:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you have two issues:

1. You are setting the new value with `scope="page"` but you state the value is still "hi" on the next request. You need to use `scope="session"` for the value to be persisted over mutiple requests.
2. You are setting the value to be " ". This is neither `null` nor `empty` - it is a String value of a single space. You might want to try setting the value to `${null}` or "".

Comment: isn't scope value as request will not do? why to maintain the variable in session and lower the performance?

Comment: request scope is for that single request only - they state in their question they want the variable available "for the next request". As for "lower performance" I very much doubt. Show me your benchmarks for the two and I might believe you (remember: benchmark don't optimize).

Comment: i put the scope="session" with value "good". but this time it stores the value hi is not update with good.Any way thanks for help..i have done change in my approach..

Comment: If it is going back through the same controller method then your `model.addAttribute("message" "hi");` will clobber the value you put in the session. I assumed you were then hitting a different URL.